# Is there a quota / limit of 1500 for google contacts api sync?

Tags: api, google-contacts-api, quota

I am using a Thunderbird mail plugin "gContactSync"
This week myself & 10+ other users found the plugin can only sync 1500 contacts.
Nothing has changed in the plugin or thunderbird.

We believe Google API contacts has changed.
Can anyone please advise what the 1500 limit / quota for syncing contacts is?
How do we resolve?